# Invalid content was found starting with element 'target-cpu-utilization'

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am running three app-engine services, This is my `appening-web.xml` from one service

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <!-- <application>sandbox-10fb8</application> -->
  <application>XXX-184914</application> 
  <version>1</version>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
   <runtime>java8</runtime>
  <use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>
  <service>XXX</service>

</appengine-web-app>
```

This is what i see in my cloud app-engine console

```
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: automatic
  max_idle_instances: automatic
  min_pending_latency: automatic
  max_pending_latency: automatic
```

When i use `mvn appengin:update` it works just fine.  so i thought adding scaling config. and this what i did

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <!-- <application>sandbox-10fb8</application> -->
  <application>XXX-184914</application> 
  <version>1</version>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
  <automatic-scaling>
    <target-cpu-utilization>0.95</target-cpu-utilization>
    <min-idle-instances>1</min-idle-instances>
    <min-instances>1</min-instances>
    <max-instances>2</max-instances>
    <max-concurrent-requests>50</max-concurrent-requests>
  </automatic-scaling>
   <runtime>java8</runtime>
  <use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>
  <service>XXX</service>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Now when i do the same mvn command i get following error

```
 against C:\Users\mc7101\.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-java-sdk\1.9.51\appengine-java-sdk\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.51\docs\appengine-web.xsd
  Caused by: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'target-cpu-utilization'. One of '{"http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":min-pending-latency, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":max-pending-latency, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":min-idle-instances, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":max-idle-instances, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":max-concurrent-requests, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":min-num-instances, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":max-num-instances, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":cool-down-period-sec, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":cpu-utilization, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":target-network-sent-bytes-per-sec, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":target-network-sent-packets-per-sec, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":target-network-received-bytes-per-sec, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":target-network-received-packets-per-sec, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":target-disk-write-bytes-per-sec, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":target-disk-write-ops-per-sec, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":target-disk-read-bytes-per-sec, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":target-disk-read-ops-per-sec, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":target-request-count-per-sec, "http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0":target-concurrent-requests}' is expected.
Please see the logs [C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg5084302388655645727.log] for further information.
```

If i understand the clearly the error message, it is saying something wrong on how i type those tags, as it cant be found, but i copied from google [doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#scaling_elements_automatic_scaling). What really i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The `mvn appengin:update` command appears to be making use of the `appcfg` command from the GAE Java SDK (note the `appcfg` in the `appcfg5084302388655645727.log` log filename mentioned in the error message you got), which that doesn't (yet) support some of the more recently added scaling configuration parameters, including `target-cpu-utilization`. From the very doc you mentioned:

> **Important**: If you use the **appcfg** command from the App Engine SDK for Java to deploy, you cannot use this parameter in your
>   **appengine-web.xml**. Instead, set the parameter as described in [Setting Autoscaling Parameters in the API Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/setting-autoscaling-params-in-explorer), or by using
>   the [App Engine Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions/patch).